# What does Error:(13) Error: The <receiver> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent] mean and how do i fix it?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Im having problems when trying to compile my app, im trying to launch it from the dialler and the manifest file gets this error. Here is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.DialReceiver"
            android:exported="true"

            android:process=":background"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.DialReceiver"
        android:exported="true"

        android:process=":background"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Outside `<activity>` tag

Comment: when i do that   android:name=".receiver.DialReceiver" becomes an error

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol receiver and cannot resolve symbol DialReceiver

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify your manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.DialReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":background">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```