# The <receiver> element must be a direct child of the <application> element

Tags: android, android-layout

How to fix this  issue ?

**Please consider that i don't know very well programming**

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ment4">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Assignment4">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Error:(13) Error: The <receiver> element must be a direct child of the <application> element \[WrongManifestParent\] mean and how do i fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604724/what-does-error13-error-the-receiver-element-must-be-a-direct-child-of-the)

Comment: `</receiver>
        </activity>` You placed your receiver tag inside an activity tag. So it is child of activity now. Place it above or below activity.

Comment: Where should i but it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Assignment4">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```